# uiimage reports invalid size

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I'm pulling in a UIImage from an NSURL (as data) and I need to set the frame based on the size of the image.  However, the image.size.width always comes back as 0, and image.size.height comes back as a large number (my guess is the total number of bytes in the image).  Is there any way to get the proper values after an image has been downloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're printing the width and height as integers. They're CGFloats.

Or, do this to print the size:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(theImage.size));
```

Comment: Good call! Didn't even occur to me!

Comment: AAAGGGHHH!  :-)  I can't believe I did that *again*.  Sigh -- thank you!  (now to figure out why it's reporting the *wrong* values...)